# vaadin - delay component loading

Tags: vaadin-flow

We have a new vaadin 23 web app that we are trying to optimise the first page load of.

The largest components are the vaadin JavaScript files which are in excess of 500k.

Https://onepub.dev

I assume that vaadin is including some components that we aren't using on the first page.

Is there anyway to get vaadin to delay loading these components until they are needed?

Answer (score 1):

As of right now: no. There is a related ticket: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5537